# RegularExpression matches too long

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to take string between `"`, but the **regular expression** matches too long.

The code is like below:

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp =
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
 @"\".?\"" options:0 error:&error];
```

And the string matches is below:

`what_i_want" "what_I_do_not_want`

You know, I want to take only:

`what_i_want`

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `@"\"[^\"]+\""` instead.

Comment: What is that dot for? What if input string would be `text "here and also"" there` ..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use regex pattern `@"\".*?\""`